# Excel Cell.Replace issue

Tags: excel, vba, replace

When I'm using Cell.Replace to replace a variable with a date excel changes my date formatting. (See picture)

I've tried changing the ReplaceFormat option to True... see below

```
Cells.Replace What:=VariableName, Replacement:=VariableValue, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=True
```

https://photos.app.goo.gl/JswS61eYiKEC6EUt2

Comment: Okay? Do you get an error? Does it not give an error, but produces an unexpected outcome? What's the question?

Comment: Sorry, thre was no error. The picture shows the outcome of running the replace. My intention was to replace with the formatting with MM/DD/YY H:MM AM/PM

Answer (score 1):

You can use find/replace, and use a specified format when replacing.  Add this line above the `Cells.Replace...` line:

```
Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY H:MM AM/PM"
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Wayne. This appear to work, however, I have this inside of a loop where the formatting between each loop instance.

Comment: @JacobMF - Then you can just do that format once, or perhaps create a list of formatting? In any case, that sounds like it would be a new question altogether.

Comment: @JacobMF - Did this answer work for you? If so, you can flag as the answer by clicking the check mark left of the post, and it removes this post from the Unanswered queue.